# Cloudfront with no-cache In request header not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, varnish, http-caching

As we can use cloudfront for http cache / shared cache / as cdn.
cloudfront can cache based on Cache-Control headers received from origin (response headers)
But when I pass Cache-Control : no-cache as request header, I am still getting response from cloudfront where as, for HTTP cache it should hit the origin to get the response.
I have set the minimum TTL setting to 0.
Is there any way we can handle this behaviour with cloudfront ?

Comment: You probably want `no-store` here, but when you say pass do you mean sending it in the request? That cache-control header should be set in the response in your origin, not by the requester.

Comment: Yes I am passing as request header to cloudfront url not as response header. With response header from origin it's working. I want to know if cloufront support Cache-Control headers passed from request headers. Earlier we were using varnish as HTTP cache where we can get the data from origin and not from cache when we pass Cache-Control : no-cache in request header